# Periodic read timeout error in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout

I am getting read timeout error on 10th minute of every hour. All the scheduled processes from the application is stopped. So nothing scheduled from application side. So I would like to know if there is any schedule internal to es that run every hour. I have not changed any time related config in the elasticsearch.yml.

In one of the thread it was mentioned that GC stops all the communication until it finishes. I checked the logs and it shows that application threads are stopped every minute for around ~0.0009 seconds. Does es or jvm run anything periodically at frequency of hour? Is there any way to check the config?

Can someone provide me few more pointers to debug the issue.

Config:
2 node es cluster (4 core 16GB). 
es version 6.5.3

Comment: I dont know the answer and am watching this thread to see what comes out of it. But have you tried increasing the heap size?

Comment: Currently it is set to 4GB. So ideally without knowing the root cause, I do not want to increase more.

Comment: ok that is fine.

Comment: @RiteshAgrawal, can you tell, how many documents are stored and what is the load on the ES cluster, is there is any background job like bulk indexing or bulk searching happens at regular interval, which eats up your JVM and is there is anyt monitoring tool which u are using ??

Comment: You could try to hit [hot-thread](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) api when the issue occurs and it would give out the details of CPU usage per thread with stacktrace, which will be usually enough to get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal There are around 30 million documents across 20 indices with the total size of ~3GB (primary only). 
No there are no background processes scheduled from application side. Not sure anything about es internally.
Since it is deployed on on premise environment so don't have access to the monitoring console.

Comment: @AnanthaKumaran Sure. I will check the api if it provide any information.